# UIImageView leaves significant whitespace in a UITableView cell when Aspect Fit content mode is selected

Tags: ios, swift

[image]
I am using UIImageView with content mode AspectFit but my url image leaves empty spaces in top and bottom.

I already try tried using scale fill and aspect fill mode but it not working as per requirements.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row

        if(row == 0){

          let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostNewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! PostNewTableViewCell

            cell.postTitleLbl.text = commonContentList[0].commonTitle
            cell.postDateLbl.text = commonContentList[0].commonCreatedAt
           return cell


        }else if(row == 1){
            let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostNewSecondTableViewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! PostNewSecondTableViewCell

            cell.logoURL = commonContentList[0].commonImage


             return cell
        }else if(row == 2) {

            let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostNewThirdTableViewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! PostNewThirdTableViewCell
            cell.postDescLbl.text = postDescription

            return cell
      }
}
```

Comment: Can anybody help me to achieve right answer for this problem. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to set the cell height to match that of the scaled image. Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvjEqWHcyIw for a tutorial which should help.

Comment: From Apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Comment: It doesn't seems to be working for me because my image type is URL.

Answer (score 0):

First set size constaints of the `ImageView` if you haven’t. Then switch to **Scale to Fill**, and check **Clips to Bounds** box in Attributes Inspector.

Comment: My ImageView constraint are top=superview, bottom= superview, trailing = 9, leading = 9 and when I select clips to bounds with scale to fill image height seems to be huge

Comment: @Sushil dhakal I am using the same method in my current project and it works. I’m pretty sure your problem is with constraints. I can’t say a certain thing without seeing your project, but either you are connecting to wrong superview or other elements doesn’t have constraints or they’re ambigious.

Comment: Gul as I already mentioned above about my constraint and I also followed the instruction you provided but its not working for me.

Comment: @Gushil as i said you are connecting your top and bottom to the wrong superview. Make sure they're connected to cell's frame.